# Is my use of WCF async beneficial?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to quickly convert a couple of our WCF calls to use the asynchronous-generated methods. I'm still somewhat new to using async/await in our code (I'm primarily a web developer) and want to see if my approach provides some benefit.

In the code below, I still need to return the result to the caller, so the entire operation itself is still "synchronous" in perception, but doesn't appear to be starving the current thread up until the await, which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Even though my caller (Main, in this case) is not asynchronous itself (it can't be), is there still any benefit in this approach? Essentially, all I did was use the async/await keywords and used Async WCF method. Thanks.

(The console.writelines are just for testing)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = WcfAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private async static Task<bool> WcfAsync()
    {
        using (var svc = new EmailVendorService.EmailVendorServiceWCFClient())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); // Current thread ID
            try
            {
                // long running task to vendor API
                var result = await svc.ExecuteProgramAsync("SomeProgram", "start");

                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); // Outputs different thread's ID

                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty beneficial to me.

Comment: Yup, If `ExecuteProgramAsync` is really asynchronous this appears beneficial. Side note: atleast log exception. Don't swallow..

Comment: Yes, please ignore the "exception handling" :-)

Comment: FOLLOW-UP: Would bypassing the async/await wrapper and go directly to just using svc.ExecuteProgramAsync("SomeProgram", "start").Result still provide benefit? In my tests, it still appears to work and is not blocking the thread, though it's using the same thread ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you're really going to end up with, then there's no benefit. You are saving a thread by using the `async` WCF client, but then you're blocking a thread in `Main`.

However, if your final solution is a UI project, then there is a benefit: you can avoid blocking the UI thread. Or if your final solution is an ASP.NET website, then there is a benefit: you save the thread by using `async` but you don't have to block any threads to do it. In desktop applications (e.g., Console/UI apps), threads are pretty "cheap". The primary benefit of `async` is to avoid blocking the UI (if there is one).

If you're doing several concurrent calls, then `async` could help make your code clearer. But if it's just a single WCF call in a console app, then there's not really any benefit.

Comment: It won't be in a console app - I was just using that as a test-bed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We use async for long running process where you don't want to freez the UI. If you are using Async Method

1. If you have dependent task on each other e.g. calculation of one
   result you want to put in other result then you need to impliment
   Async.
2. if you task is indipendent then it will always benifit you for using the Async method.
3. any indipendent task you should put in async method. that will give you responsive and rich ui.
4. Async also provide you time token for time out operation.

what Async dose is it will use Thread pool to execute your task. Which is managed by .net fremwork it self.